# How to use a binary variable to build a logistic regression model?

Tags: r, binary, logistic-regression, numeric

As you can see, this is the structure of my dependent variable (`G3`):

[image: structure information of G3]

`G3` is student's final period grade. It is a binary variable, if `G3`<10, students fail; if `G3`>=10, students pass. It is represented by "1" means fail, "2" means pass.

Now I'm going to build a logistic regression model. I need to convert this binary variable into a numeric variable, and we assumed that if the dependent variable G3 is equal to 1 if students failed, if G3 is equal to 0 if students passed. What should I do?

And I checked the structure of G3 again:

[image: try to convert G3 into numeric variable first]

It turned into numeric variable, but "fail" or "pass" still represent by "1" and "2". How can i change them to "1" and "0"?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to help you, we would appreciate an 'MRE': https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  This means, provide us with sample data so that we can reproduce your particular problem

Comment: in general it's better to provide information by cutting and pasting text rather than posting screen captures, where possible ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
performance$G3 <- 2-performance$G3
```

?

Alternatively, you could have started at the beginning with

```
performance$G3 <- ifelse(performance$G3=="fail",0,1)
```

Finally, you can use a factor variable as a response. From `?binomial`, if the response variable is a factor,

> ... ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not
>             having the first level (and hence usually of having the
>             second level).

You'd have to change the order of the levels, e.g.

```
 performance$G3 <- factor(performance$G3, levels=c("pass", "fail"))
```